# How can I make split(/\t/, $STRING) detect empty values when $STRING ends with "\t\t"?

Tags: string, perl, whitespace, trailing

How can I  make `split(/\t/, $STRING)` detect empty items when `$STRING` ends with `"\t\t"`?

Using Perl script, I am trying to split strings based on  as a separator between items then count and use these items. But, when the strings end with a combination s, the script doesn't count empty items.

Example:

`string="value1\tvalue2\t\t\t\t"` (value1, value2 and 4 empty items)

but it counts 2 items (value1, value2):

```
$STRING="value1\tvalue2\t\t\t\t";
print $STRING."\n";
my @F = split(/\t/, $STRING);
print scalar(@F)."\n";

# The number of items must match the number of header name
if( scalar(@F) == 6 )
            {
                    print  "Done \n";
            }
```

the code prints:

```
value1  value2      
2
```

while what is expected is:

```
value1  value2  
6
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the `split` line by adding `-1` as a parameter:

```
my @F = split(/\t/, $STRING, -1);
```

Output:

```
value1  value2              
6
Done
```

Per [`perldoc split`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/split), the parameters to `split` are `PATTERN, EXPR, LIMIT`.  In your current situation, "LIMIT is omitted so "trailing empty fields are stripped."

By adding the `-1` value for `LIMIT`:

> If LIMIT is negative, it is treated as if it were instead arbitrarily large; as many fields as possible are produced.

So a negative final argument prevents `split` from discarding trailing fields.